# Sum of linear combination of unit vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, induction, normed-spaces

For any unit vectors $v_{1}, \ldots, v_{n}$ we have
$$
\sum_{a_{1}, \ldots, a_{n} \in\{1,-1\}}\left\|a_{1} \boldsymbol{v}_{1}+\cdots+a_{n} \boldsymbol{v}_{n}\right\|^{2}=n \cdot 2^{n}
$$

What would be the result of,
$$
\sum_{a_{1}, \ldots, a_{n} \in\{1,-1\}}\left\|a_{1} \boldsymbol{v}_{1}+\cdots+a_{n} \boldsymbol{v}_{n}+a_1a_2v_{n+1}+a_1a_3v_{n+2}\cdots\cdots (a_1a_2\cdots a_n v_{2^n-1})\right\|^{2}
$$
would be, if $v_{1}, \ldots, v_{2^n-1}$ are unit vectors. The coefficients are products of the power set elements of $a=\{a_1\cdots a_n\}$.

All vectors are in real 3-d space.

My initial guess is that it would depend on the unit vectors considered, unlike the first case, which holds for any unit vectors. If that's the case, then what would be the upper bound on that sum?. What set of unit vectors would yield that sum?

First result is proved using induction.

Proof. For $n=1$ we have
$$
\sum_{a_{1} \in\{1,-1\}}\left\|a_{1} \boldsymbol{v}_{1}\right\|^{2}=\left\|\boldsymbol{v}_{1}\right\|^{2}+\left\|-\boldsymbol{v}_{1}\right\|^{2}=2
$$
Let us assume that equation holds for $n=k$ . Then for $n=k+1$ we have
$$
\sum_{a_{1}, \ldots, a_{k}, a_{k+1} \in\{1,-1\}}\left\|a_{1} \boldsymbol{v}_{1}+\cdots+a_{k} \boldsymbol{v}_{k}+a_{k+1} \boldsymbol{v}_{k+1}\right\|^{2}
$$
If we write out the sum over $a_{k+1}$ explicitly, we obtain
$$
\sum_{a_{1}, \ldots, a_{k} \in\{1,-1\}}\left(\left\|a_{1} \boldsymbol{v}_{1}+\cdots+a_{k} \boldsymbol{v}_{k}+\boldsymbol{v}_{k+1}\right\|^{2}+\left\|a_{1} \boldsymbol{v}_{1}+\cdots+a_{k} \boldsymbol{v}_{k}-\boldsymbol{v}_{k+1}\right\|^{2}\right)
$$
We can use the parallelogram identity
$$
|| \boldsymbol{u}_{1}+\boldsymbol{u}_{2}\left\|^{2}+\right\| \boldsymbol{u}_{1} - \boldsymbol{u}_{2} \|^{2}=2\left(\left\|\boldsymbol{u}_{1}\right\|^{2}+\left\|\boldsymbol{u}_{2}\right\|^{2}\right)
$$
which holds for any two vectors $u_{1}$ and $u_{2},$ to simplify the sum as follows:
$$
\sum_{a_{1}, \ldots, a_{k} \in\{1,-1\}} 2\left(\left\|a_{1} v_{1}+\cdots+a_{k} v_{k}\right\|^{2}+\left\|\boldsymbol{v}_{k+1}\right\|^{2}\right)
$$
We know that $\boldsymbol{v}_{k+1}$ is a unit vector and we have assumed that holds for $n=k ;$ therefore
simplifies to $2\left(k \cdot 2^{k}+2^{k}\right)=(k+1) \cdot 2^{k+1}$